# lsass.exe, Https, IIS and High Concurrent Connections

Tags: https, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have **Windows Server 2012 r2**, Hosting multiple websites on ***http*** and ***https*** protocols.

when the current **connections** reach ***26000*** the ***https*** is not served although the http is serving normally .

After the ***36000*** connections the http also is not serving any website.

also the ***lsass*** process takes about ***20 to 25 percent*** of the cpu staring from 26000 connections.

is there a way to increase the number of connections served or do I need another server behind load balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the SSL certificate RSA key size from 4048 to 2024 and it works just fine .

The reason that the processor take too much calculations to encrypt and decrypt bigger key size.